# iOS - TextField recommend clear button behavior

Tags: ios, user-interface, standards

In interface builder, there is a option that lets the user clear a `TextField` when they hit the (x) key. Since I think this option is extremely useful, I want to implement it in as many `TextField`s as possible.
However, the default implementation of the option is "never appears", and I want to keep as many default values as possible (because I think Apple considers the default interface behavior very well).
So my question is: when should I change the value? And if so, to what should I change it (always, when editing, or unless edition)? Here are some occasions I need to know:

- On a table view
- when the user enters his account details (email, password, name, etc.).

If you come up with other cases I should consider, please let me know!

Sorry, but I couldn't find any documents about this part of the UI in apple's documentation (which is very good and precise when it deals with standards).

---

This question is not about how to enable the key. Instead, it is *when* to enable it. I know it is my app and I can do whatever I want but I know how non-standardized apps feel like. So I want mine to be as standardized as possible so that the user doesn't experience any weird or usual behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ABSOLUTELY depends on the you app design. Apple gives you these four options and it's up to you, which behavior fits your needs best, Apple does not care at all.

I personally only use it "while editing". In the past, I only used them for login or sign up forms.

Comment: But the user will. I was wondering in what case the button should appear and when it shouldn't. Could you give me some cases, when the button should appear and when it shouldn't? When do you use it?

Comment: It's good you ask for our experience and examples. Your question sounds a bit like you were asking for a fixed "set of rules"

Comment: Because I kind of am. But since there doesn't seem to be any, I'd also like to hear your experiences :)

Comment: I edited my answer, I prefer to them in sign up forms, login forms and similar... For most other cases they don't make many sense for me ;)